# How to make USB drive to detect as a CD drive programatically

Tags: c++, windows, installation, usb

I am working on project in `C++\MFC` where client requirement is, 
application should be installed on the USB drive 
and
also should run the same as soon as the USB is attached to the system.

**For first task** i.e. the application should install on USB.

After searching I came to know that it is possible by just changing the installation path.

But, **for second part** I am bit confused how I can do that.

As I know `windows XP SP3, Win7, Win8` Does not support the `autorun` for USB.

While googling I came to know that windows support `autorun` for CD/DVD.

So, Is there any way so that I can change the USB device setting to detect it as a CD drive from programming.

Comment: Do you want to to autorun on a virgin Windows machine, or one where you're allowed to install some component before the USB disk is plugged in? If the former, then their sysadmin should scream bloody murder.

Comment: Do any of the settings in Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->AutoPlay work for this scenario?  I haven't played with all of these settings to see if any of them work for USB.  There's one at the bottom of the page called "Software and Games". I'm not certain if that setting applies for USB

Comment: @selbie I have tried this too but not able to make it work